# generic property panel

Tags: django

I need to evaluate the usage of django in implementing a back-office application. It should be able to do CRUD of about 150-200 different object types. As it's a *back-office* application it will contain a lot of grids/tables.

Many objects can have a bunch of associated properties. There are properties of the following types

- simple text
- one or several values chosen from a static list
- one or several values chosen from a dynamic list with a possibility of search
- custom types

These properties are defined in multiple languages.

This application should be highly customizable. All properties and the list of languages should be somehow defined in the model and then the application automatically creates a grid to show/edit them.

Currently we have a java application which displays them like that

[image]

Is django a good choice to implement this kind of application?

Do you know good references of django open-source back-office applications of similar type?

Will it be difficult to implement such dynamic property panels using django?

Comment: Django would not be a bad choice for this type of project. The models and relations you mention should be straight-forward to build, and as well the multi-language part. The interface you have to build on your own, I don't think adapting the django-admin would be a good way to go.
For an example project, take a look at [transifex](http://www.transifex.net) [.org for the source] - especially the translation-editor.